# Creating my own slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

This is more like a homework done for myselft and to myself.

It will be useful and i need to practice, so i was wondering on how can i create a valid slider using javascript (jquery mostly)

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/htArE/

I have 3 divs, and i'm trying to put only one with red borders at a time:

This is what i've got so far:

```
<div id="slidez0" class="active">slider 1</div>
<div id="slidez1" class="inactive">slide 2</div>
<div id="slidez2" class="inactive">slide 3</div>​

setInterval(slider(), 2000);


function slider(){
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        if($('#slidez'+i).hasClass('1')){
               $('#slidez'+i).css('border','solid 1px red');
               $('#slidez1').css('border','solid 1px white');
               $('#slidez2').css('border','solid 1px white');
        }else if($('#slidez'+i).hasClass('2')){
               $('#slidez'+i).css('border','solid 1px red');
               $('#slidez0').css('border','solid 1px white');
               $('#slidez2').css('border','solid 1px white');
        }else if($('#slidez'+i).hasClass('3')){
               $('#slidez'+i).css('border','solid 1px red');
               $('#slidez0').css('border','solid 1px white');
               $('#slidez1').css('border','solid 1px white');
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/htArE/

Actually, i don't know what to do in the function slider, i have three sliders, so they will alternate classes like this (1 for active, 0 for inactive):

```
1 0 0  - first slider active;
0 1 0  - after setInterval, second slider active, first inactive;
0 0 1  - after another setInterval, third slider active, first and second inactive;

1 0 0  - Restart slider, first slider active, other inactive;
```

​IF you don't understand something on my question, please comment bellow so i can edit.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/htArE/2/ If it is I will explain it to you.

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo, that's what i was looking for, although i don't really understand the code... Please reply as an answer, so i can up vote and comment there :)

Comment: Sure! It's not that hard, you'll see.

Comment: I've read it carefully, 

it does remove the class "selected" from the previous slider and adds it to the present one;

The problem here would be if i wanted to add options like buttons to select the slider "1,2,3" for example, or even stop event when on mouse over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the solution below working at: http://jsfiddle.net/htArE/4/

The javascript...

```
var slide = $('.slide'),
    count = 0,
    max_count = slide.length - 1,

    slideIt = function slideIt() {
        slide.removeClass('selected').eq(count).addClass('selected');
        count = ++count > max_count ? 0 : count;
        setTimeout(slideIt, 2000);
    };

    slideIt();
```

... for the html...

```
<div class="slide selected">slide 1</div>
<div class="slide">slide 2</div>
<div class="slide">slide 3</div>
```

... and css...

```
.slide {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.selected {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**ASIDE**

It was taking me too long to write the explanation to the code for some weird reason, so I just gave up. I'll instead post a simplified version of it below, and hopefully you'll understand it that way.

Comment: I don't think the code will fit my needs, need buttons to navigate through the sliders :(

I'll give you the check mark you the answer since you responded to my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you should set it up as a jQuery plugin.
Follow [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-simple-content-slider-jquery-plugin/), they follow good practices.

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-simple-content-slider-jquery-plugin/